# Busca em tempo real economizando servidor?

Tags: jquery, json

Olá, criei um script em `jQuery` que efetua consulta no banco de dados, baseando-se no que a pessoa digitou em um campo `input`. A cada tecla que o usuário digita, o script faz um novo requerimento para a minha `API` e isso é um problema, já que pretendo contratar uma hospedagem barata. Portanto, eu queria saber como posso melhorar o seguinte script para que não precise ficar perguntando toda hora pro servidor e gastando os recursos do servidor que pretendo contratar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').keyup(function(event) {
        var t = $('#input').val();
        $.getJSON('api', {word: t}, function(json, textStatus) {
            // Em caso de sucesso, essa função será ativa
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Qual é a quantidade de registros no banco de dados que o servidor pode retornar? Se não for muito grande, você pode transferir todos na primeira requisição e apenas filtrá-los com o JavaScript.

Comment: O site que estou desenvolvendo é um site de conteúdo dinâmico, ou seja, sempre terão novas atualizações, consequentemente um banco de dados grande...

Comment: Então você pode estipular um mínimo de caracteres para começar a buscar no banco e refazê-la a cada 2 ou 3 novos caracteres.

Comment: cria uma função `on click` em vez de `keyup` e assim a consulta só será feita quando o usuário acabar de digitar e clicar num botão, ou clicar `enter` para avançar.

Comment: Você quer reduzir o número de consultas ao servidor, mas não disse os criterios que precisam ser seguidos para isso. Existem várias formas de reduzir o número de requisições, algumas vão te atender muito bem, outras não tão bem. Lembre-se que se você chega ao ponto de prejudicar a usabilidade do usuário para ganhar performance, você está fazendo errado. Se não tem mais o que melhorar (sem prejudicar o usuário) no código, então você tem que contratar mais hardware ou buscar outras tecnologias. E não se engane, os bancos de dados suportam muito mais "tranco" do que você imagina.

Comment: [Essa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210855/11886) serviu para você @AndersonSantos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma função `on click` em vez de `keyup` e assim a consulta só será feita quando o usuário acabar de digitar e clicar num botão, ou clicar <kbd>enter</kbd> para avançar com a pesquisa.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#botao-pesquisar').click(function(){
        var t = $('#input').val();
        $.getJSON('api', {word: t}, function(json, textStatus) {
            // Em caso de sucesso, essa função será ativa
        });
    })
    $('#input').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){ // Tecla Enter primida
            $('#botao-pesquisar').click(); // Dispara o evento click no botão de pesquisa
        }
    });
});
```

Pode não ser a maneira mais perfeita, mas já reduz consideravelmente a consulta constante em cada tecla primida.